# Use Generic Lambda with std::find_if

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

My compiler is gcc-4.9 and I compile with `-std=c++14`.
I have the following code, which doesn't compile.

```
 set<int> pal;
 set<tuple<int, int, int>> pal_group;

 // ... populate pal & pal_group

 auto itr_pal = max_element(pal.begin(), pal.end());
 auto itr_pal_group =
     find_if(
         pal_group.begin(), pal_group.end(), [&itr_pal] (auto pal_tuple) {
             return true;
         }
     );
```

However, the above code will compile once I start to actually use `pal_tuple`.
e.g.

```
     find_if(
         pal_group.begin(), pal_group.end(), [&itr_pal] (auto pal_tuple) {
             int pal;
             tie(pal, ignore, ignore) = pal_tuple;
             return pal == *itr_pal;
         }
     );
```

My suspicion is that the compiler cannot figure out the type of `pal_tuple` without me actually using it like a `tuple<int, int, int>`.
However, the prototype of an unary predicate seems to indicate that the type of `pal_tuple` can only be that a variation of `tuple<int, int, int>` (e.g. `const`, `const T&`, etc.)?

The following is from cpprefernece.com:

```
The signature of the predicate function should be equivalent to the following:

    bool pred(const Type &a);

The signature does not need to have const &, but the function must not modify the objects passed to it.
The type Type must be such that an object of type InputIt can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to Type. ​
```

---

I would like to find out why the compiler cannot figure out the type of `pal_tuple` without me actually using it.

Thanks,

Edit:
This is a mistake... So the compiler was actually only giving me warnings, but I thought it was an error. I will be more careful in the future before posting questions...

```
g++-4.9 -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra p4.cpp -o p4.exec
p4.cpp: In instantiation of 'main()::<lambda(auto:1)> [with auto:1 = std::tuple<int, int, int>]':
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0/4.9.1/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:231:30:   required from 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<_Predicate>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::tuple<int, int, int> >; _Predicate = main()::<lambda(auto:1)>]'
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0/4.9.1/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:104:50:   required from '_InputIterator std::__find_if(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Predicate, std::input_iterator_tag) [with _InputIterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::tuple<int, int, int> >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<main()::<lambda(auto:1)> >]'
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0/4.9.1/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:162:43:   required from '_Iterator std::__find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Predicate) [with _Iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::tuple<int, int, int> >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<main()::<lambda(auto:1)> >]'
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0/4.9.1/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:3804:45:   required from '_IIter std::find_if(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::tuple<int, int, int> >; _Predicate = main()::<lambda(auto:1)>]'
p4.cpp:49:9:   required from here
p4.cpp:41:66: warning: unused parameter 'pal_tuple' [-Wunused-parameter]
             pal_group.begin(), pal_group.end(), [&itr_pal] (auto pal_tuple) {
                                                                  ^
```

Comment: @Deduplicator, hmm.. seems like it's commonly known as generic lambdas now. When I first read the proposal for a generic lambda, I think it was called Polymorphic lambda... I'll correct the title.

Comment: Works fine in Clang...

Comment: @KerrekSB, which Clang version you're using? My clang doesn't seem to accept `-std=c++14`...

Comment: Nightly build, with `-std=c++1y`...

Comment: clang version 3.5.0 (tags/RELEASE_350/final 217394), using libc++ on Linux-x86_64 works as well (coliru)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is both valid, and compiled with gcc 4.9 when I tried it (barring some warnings).  Your problem is not with the posted code, but lies elsewhere.

In the future, please post the actual error message, and actually type the code you post into your compiler and watch your compiler generate said error.

Comment: It was my mistake, the compiler only gave me warnings but I took it as error... I'll be more careful in the future before posting questions.